# MVC ViewBag Is Not Appearing In Views At All

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, controller, viewbag

Several of my pages on MVC (which had ViewBag.Message by default when setting up MVC) doesn't display at all in the view.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
ViewBag.Test = "Test";
return view();
}
```

Razor View:

```
Index.cshtml

<p> Hello @ViewBag.Test </p>
```

I have no idea why my viewbag isn't appearing?

Comment: `<p> Hello @ViewBag.Message</p>`

Comment: Sorry I was meant to write Test

Comment: 'return view();` needs a capital `V`

Comment: Must be a typo... The code wouldn't compile if it was like this in the IDE

Answer (score 0):

In your controller is the name of the viewbag variable ViewBag.Message but in your view you are looking at @ViewBag.Test .

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your typos when typing out the question, your code is correct.

Make sure when you are checking to see if it works you are looking at the correct page, I would imagine you should have '/Home/Index' in the URL.

Try changing the string 'Test' into something long so that you don't miss it if it really is being displayed.

Comment: The problem is solved , I just rebuilt the solution. Thank you